# TradingView Widget not loading on Android 6.0

Tags: java, android, android-studio, webview, tradingview-api

I'm developing an app with Tradingview widget on Android 6.0 (Marshmallow)

I am running the tradingview code in WebView but it is not showing the chart.

[image]

This is my TradingView Widget code;

```
WebView webView = findViewById(R.id.webviewer);
String symbol = getIntent().getStringExtra("symbol");
String interval = getIntent().getStringExtra("interval");

String data = "<!-- TradingView Widget BEGIN -->\n" +
                "<div class=\"tradingview-widget-container\">\n" +
                "  <div id=\"tradingview_357eb\"></div>\n" +
                "  <div class=\"tradingview-widget-copyright\"><a href=\"https://tr.tradingview.com/symbols/"+symbol+"/?exchange=BINANCE\" rel=\"noopener\" target=\"_blank\"><span class=\"blue-text\">"+symbol+" Chart</span></a></div>\n" +
                "  <script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"https://s3.tradingview.com/tv.js\"></script>\n" +
                "  <script type=\"text/javascript\">\n" +
                "  new TradingView.widget(\n" +
                "  {\n" +
                "  \"width\": 300,\n" +
                "  \"height\": 200,\n" +
                "  \"symbol\": \"BINANCE:"+symbol+"\",\n" +
                "  \"interval\": \""+interval+"\",\n" +
                "  \"timezone\": \"Europe/Istanbul\",\n" +
                "  \"theme\": \"light\",\n" +
                "  \"style\": \"1\",\n" +
                "  \"locale\": \"en\",\n" +
                "  \"toolbar_bg\": \"#f1f3f6\",\n" +
                "  \"enable_publishing\": false,\n" +
                "  \"hide_side_toolbar\": false,\n" +
                "  \"save_image\": false,\n" +
                "  \"studies\": [\n" +
                "    \"BB@tv-basicstudies\",\n" +
                "    \"RSI@tv-basicstudies\",\n" +
                "    \"StochasticRSI@tv-basicstudies\"\n" +
                "  ],\n" +
                "  \"container_id\": \"tradingview_357eb\"\n" +
                "}\n" +
                "  );\n" +
                "  </script>\n" +
                "</div>\n" +
                "<!-- TradingView Widget END -->";

        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.loadData(data, "text/html", "utf-8");
```

**I tried it on Android 8.0 and it works but not on 6.0. Why? Am I missing something?**